# Determine which level i'm in the JSON tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I may have a simple problem, but i can't figure it out. If I have a multy denominational JSON array like so:

```
[
    {
        "name":"one",
        "children":
        [
            {
                "name":"two",
                "children":
                [
                    {
                        "name":"two",
                        "children": []
                    }, 
                    ... 
                ]

            },
            ...
        ]

    }
]
```

I want to determine what level i'm at. If I was going to loop true all the first entities what will be printed is bellow:

```
one -|
     two -> View Children
```

Once "`View Children`" will be clicked:

```
one -|
     two -| 
          three -> View Children || Go Back.
```

And if "`Go Back`" is clicked we go back to:

```
one -|
     two -> View Children
```

So It's similar to a Hierarchy. I can't figure out how to make the back button work. I was able to figure out the go forward using this peace of code:

```
level = obj; // OBJ is the json data.

function inside(events){
    temp = "";
    for (i in events) {
      temp += "<li id='"+events[i].id+"' class='"+events[i].type+"' index='"+i+"''>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+events[i].name+ "</li>";
    }
    return temp;
}

text += inside(obj);

$('#filebrowser').on('click','li.folder',function(e){

    var index =  $(this).attr('index');
    var html = "<li class='folder back' index='"+index+"'>back</li>";

    if(level[index].children){
        html = html + inside(level.[index].children);
        level = level[index].children;
    } 

    $('#filebrowser').html(html);
    e.stopPropagation();

});
```

I just wanted to say this is can be dynamic, many go back's should occur, so storing the back obj in a variable is not going to cut it.

Comment: perhaps approaching this from wrong angle and could create all html at the beginning and then just manipulate visibility of children by manipulating the DOM. A demo would help showing more about what your higher level objectives are

Comment: As an aside, a terminology quibble: [you're not dealing with JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) - your data may have been _transmitted_ as JSON, but the variables you're working with in the code shown reference arrays or objects, not JSON.

Comment: A fiddle/jsBin would be really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally [stacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) are used to keep track of things like navigation history. Most programming languages include implementations of some sort of a stack structure. In Javascript stack functionality is built into the [`Array` structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Check out the [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) methods.

As you navigate forward you can `push()` the last page onto the history stack. As the back button is pressed you can `pop()` entries off in the same order they were added, until you reach the first entry.

It might look something like this:

```
var backStack = [];
$('#filebrowser').on('click','li.folder',function(e){

    var index =  $(this).attr('index');
    var html = "<li class='folder back' index='"+index+"'>back</li>";

    if(level[index].children){
        html = html + inside(level.[index].children);
        level = level[index].children;
    } 

    backStack.push($('#filebrowser').html);
    $('#filebrowser').html(html);
    e.stopPropagation();

});
```

Then on back button pressed:

```
$('#filebrowser').html(backStack.pop());
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: No, she is not talking about the `browser's BACK` button :)

Comment: `<li class='folder back' index='"+index+"'>back</li>` see?

Comment: I am also not talking about the browser's back button. I'm talking about keeping track of which level of the hierarchy you're at by using an `Array`.

Comment: in that case charlietfl's comment is a better approach

Comment: This looks really what I'm lookig for, Can you intemperate this in the example?

Comment: Edited to show an example. This is mostly for learning basic data structures. For code that does things the "right" way then roXon and charlietfl are probably right, you should show/hide elements in the DOM using css classes or something, instead of adding them dynamically in Javascript.

Comment: @bmceldowney I figured it out. Never really knew about this kinda of technique. Thank you. +1;